# Outlook com: Avoid Security alert without redemption and without changing security settings

Tags: c#, outlook

is there a way to avoid security alerts in outlook without using redemption or changing the local security settings?

We send and read mails / appointments via COM with a c# / .net application.

I heard there could be a way of digitally sign the application. Is that true ? I can't find informations about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your options are listed at http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52

Digitally signing your app will do nothing, but installing an up-to-date Anti Virus product should help.